# Django: how to have a while loop that runs in the background process?

Tags: python, django

How would I be able to use a while loop in the background process of my django project?

I want my project to run a while loop even when the web app is not on.

How would I be able to do that?

Command Line management? or Celery? or Cron job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try Celery?

Comment: How about using multi thread?

Comment: @Antoine With django celery would be a good choice with rabbitmq/redis as message broker or if you can integrate async in your code that would also be a good option

Comment: If I use celery can I then easily integrate it with Heroku?

Comment: You can also try django background tasks :  http://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  . DB-backed work queue. Easy/simple setup.

Comment: The proper solution depends on what you want to do in this "while loop" so please explain your real use case.

Comment: will it work even when my project is not running?

Comment: I send an email every time I receive an information from an API.

Comment: You can also create a simple daemon with supervisord or similar https://gist.github.com/dkarchmer/52c580477b575c6592f683583f6cf7e1

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I send an email to users every time I receive an information from an API.

Comment: @Antoine how do you "receive information from an API" ?  But anyway, it looks like what you want is an async task queue (Celery or something else depending on volumes / scalability needs / admin abilities etc).